# Show post only from array - WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, post, advanced-custom-fields

I have array which generate ACF. I would like to display all the posts whose IDs are in the array.
This code:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r(get_field('wpisyx')) ; 
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

show me all id:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 911
    [1] => 1088
    [2] => 895
    [3] => 1069
    [4] => 915
    [5] => 873
    [6] => 470
    [7] => 515
    [8] => 1082
    [9] => 844
    [10] => 676
    [11] => 697
    [12] => 685
    [13] => 516
    [14] => 643
    [15] => 620
    [16] => 739
    [17] => 522
    [18] => 521
    [19] => 646
    [20] => 572
    [21] => 551
)
```

I want the post order to be the same as in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [WP query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) and make loop with it

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => get_field('wpisyx')));
```

Then, using typic WP loop, display them in a manner that you need:

```
if ($the_query->have_posts()) 
{
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts()) 
    {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else 
{
    // no posts found
}
```